# Sending a serialized data from js to server side in a variable

Tags: javascript, python, django, serialization, query-string

I am trying to send a serialized data through query string/variable in a url. As you know when we do a serialize in js it builds a query string itself. I am sending this data to server side which is written in django. How can i do this or how can i collect the data in the django code.

This is what i am doing.

```
selected = $('input:checkbox:checked').serialize();
```

This gives me the result as `multiselect_select_month=10&multiselect_select_month=11&multiselect_select_month=05`

I want to send this in a url with other variables, and collect the hole string (`multiselect_select_month=10&multiselect_select_month=11&`) in a single variable.
Something like

```
serialized = 'multiselect_select_month=10&multiselect_select_month=11'
```

At the server side i am writing `serialized = request.GET.get('serialized', '')`

How can i send that serialized string(which is a query string) in a single variable so that i can catch that at the server side.

NB: I want to send other variables also with the above serialized data.

Comment: So, what exactly is your question?

Comment: My question is how can i send that serialized string(which is a query string) in a single variable so that i can catch that at the server side.

Comment: Just append it as a parameter to your HTTP GET / link / however you're contacting the server: `"htpp://some.request.com/?" + serialized `

Comment: Yeah i have tried this one, but it gives me only first 'multiselect_select_month'. I need all the 'multiselect_select_month' in a single variable, and it is unknown how many 'multiselect_select_month' it may contain.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. each `multiselect_select_month` is overwriting the one before it.
I'll see if I can whip up a answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to URL-Encode `serialized`, then you can send it in a single variable.

```
serialized = encodeURIComponent(serialized);
var link = "http://host.com/?data=" + serialized;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code joins all `multiselect_select_month` values into 1 parameter.
(With the added bonus of significantly reducing the parameter length)

```
var multiSelects = [];
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
    multiSelects.push(this.value);
});
var parameter = "?multiselect_select_month=" + multiSelects.join(',');
//Will return "?multiselect_select_month=10,11,05" instead of "multiselect_select_month=10&multiselect_select_month=11&multiselect_select_month=05"
```

You can then get the `ultiselect_select_month` parameter server-side, and `explode` it on `','`:

```
string.split('10,11,05', ',')
```